# I want to rewrite URL by .htaccess in php http://www.domain.com/door?door=french-doors to http://www.domain.com/door/french-doors

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, urlhelper

please help me rewrite URL by .htaccess

```
 http://www.domain.com/door?door=casement-doors
```

to

```
 http://www.domain.com/door/casement-doors.
```

Comment: And your question is ? We're here to help with your issues, not to do your work.

Comment: yes plz help me ,   rewrite URL by .htaccess in php http://www.domain.com/door?door=casement-doors to http://www.domain.com/door/casement-doors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^door=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^door /door/%1? [NC,L,R]
```